# For each $(i, j) ∈ I × I$ let $C_{(i, j)} = A_i × B_j$, and let $P = I × I$ . Prove that $∪_{p∈P}C_p = (∪_{i∈I} A_i) × (∪_{i∈I} B_i)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is Velleman's exercise 4.1.11.b:

For each $(i, j) ∈ I × I$ let $C_{(i, j)} = A_i × B_j$, and let $P = I × I$ . Prove that $∪_{p∈P}C_p = (∪_{i∈I} A_i) × (∪_{i∈I} B_i)$.

My problem is with the proper translation of "$∪_{p∈P}C_p = (∪_{i∈I} A_i) × (∪_{i∈I} B_i)$". I believe the correct translation of the above statement is:

$∃(i,j) ∈ I^2((x,y) ∈ (A_i × B_j)) \iff ∃i ∈ I(x ∈A_i) \land ∃i ∈ I(y ∈B_i)$.

But I doubt it! Because if the above translation will be correct, then how one can use (instantiate) $y$ and $B_j$ to prove $y ∈ B_i$ for instance?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend actually writing out what you mean, not just using symbols. The problem is to do with pairs of points, not indices of sets! The question is whether taking unique pairs of points from each $A_i$ and each $B_i$   (i.e., $(a,b) \in A_i\times B_j$ for some $i,j$) is the same as taking all points from each $A_i$ and all points in $B_j$ and then taking pairs (i.e., $(a,b) \in \bigcup_i A_i \times \bigcup_j B_j$). My answer gave the details of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write how you can do it your way. adfriedman’s answer goes another way, using the fact that equality of sets is equivalent to mutual inclusion. For all sets $D, D'$, $D=D'\iff\forall x(x\in D\iff x\in D')$. This may be a definition of equality of sets or a theorem. From where I am sitting, your translation seems correct. You forgot to bind $x$ and $y$ by universal quantifiers.

I do not understand how you want to instantiate $y$. The proof goes as follows.
$$\cup_{p∈P}C_p = (\cup_{i∈I}A_i) \times (\cup_{i∈I}B_i)$$
is equivalent to
$$\forall (x, y)((x, y)\in\cup_{p∈P}C_p \iff (x, y)\in(\cup_{i∈I}A_i) \times (\cup_{i∈I}B_i))$$
which is equivalent by definition of $C$ and a set union to
$$\forall (x, y)(\exists(i, j)\in I\times I((x, y)\in A_i\times B_j) \iff (x, y)\in(\cup_{i∈I}A_i) \times (\cup_{i∈I}B_i))$$
which is equivalent by definition of a Cartesian product of sets and a set union to
$$\forall (x, y)(\exists(i, j)\in I\times I(x\in A_i\land y\in B_j) \iff \exists i\in I(x\in A_i) \land \exists i\in I(y\in B_i)).$$

$x$ and $y$ are given. Prove the equivalence inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $i'$ and $j'$, then for any $(a, b) \in C_{(i',j')}$ by definition $a\in \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ and $b\in \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$, so $(a,b) \in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)$.
As this holds for any such $(a,b)$, we have
$$\bigcup_{(a,b) \in C_{(i',j')}}(a,b) = C_{(i',j')} \subseteq \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)$$

As this holds for all $i', j'$

$$\bigcup_{(i',j') \in P} C_{(i',j')} \subseteq \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)$$

Going the other way, for any $(a,b)\in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)$ then there exists at least one $i'$ and at least one $j'$ such that $a\in A_{i'}$ and $b\in B_{j'}$, so $(a,b) \in C_{(i', j')}$. As this holds for all $(a,b) \in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right)$, so 
$$\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\right) \subseteq \bigcup_{(i',j')\in P} C_{(i', j')}$$.

Equality follows from mutual inclusion.