# Prove that $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p=(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[For each $(i, j) ∈ I × I$ let $C_{(i, j)} = A_i × B_j$, and let $P = I × I$ . Prove that $∪_{p∈P}C_p = (∪_{i∈I} A_i) × (∪_{i∈I} B_i)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421848/for-each-i-j-%e2%88%88-i-%c3%97-i-let-c-i-j-a-i-%c3%97-b-j-and-let-p-i-%c3%97-i-pr)

This is exercise $4.1.11.b$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $\{A_i|i\in I\}$ and $\{B_i|i\in I\}$ are indexed families of sets.

$(b)$ For each $(i,j)\in I\times I$ let $C_{(i,j)}=A_i\times B_j$, and $P=I\times I$. Prove that $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p=(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p$. So we can choose some $(i_0,j_0)\in P =I\times I$ such that $(x,y)\in C_p= A_{i_0}\times B_{j_0}$ and so $x\in A_{i_0}$ and $y\in B_{j_0}$. From $i_0\in I$ and $x\in A_{i_0}$, $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Similarly, $y\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ and ergo $(x,y)\in(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$. Since $(x,y)$ is arbitrary, $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p\subseteq(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$. So $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ from which we can choose some $i_0\in I$ such that $x\in A_{i_0}$ and $y\in\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ from which we can choose some $j_0\in I$ such that $y\in B_{j_0}$. Ergo $(i_0,j_0)\in I\times I=P$ and $(x,y)\in A_{i_0}\times B_{j_0}=C_{p=(i_0,j_0)}$ and so $(x,y)\in\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p$. Since $(x,y)$ is arbitrary, $(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)\subseteq \bigcup_{p\in P}C_p$.

Ergo $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p=(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\times (\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I agree: it looks fine.